# Downloading a PDF file

Tags: android, pdf

In my application, the user needs to download PDF file from an url and store it on sdcard.
But the catch here is I can only use DefaultHttpClient to access the url.
I found couple of solutions but none used DefaultHttpClient.
After downloading the PDF, I would also likie to view the PDF in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//use this method to download the pdf file

```
 public void downloadPdfContent(String urlToDownload){

             try {

                 String fileName="xyz";
             String fileExtension=".pdf";

//           download pdf file.

                URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();
                String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydownload/";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, fileName+fileExtension);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();

               System.out.println("--pdf downloaded--ok--"+urlToDownload);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }
```

//    for viewing the pdf use this method

```
private void onPdfClick()
    {

//      String pdfFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + AstroManager.file.getName();

         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/mydownload/xyz.pdf"), "application/*");

         startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I want to use DefaulthttpClient.
In your answer, you have used HttpURLConnection

Comment: ya you can change it to DefaulthttpClient, whats the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Sorry I took time. Actually the problem was, my url was having some redirects so I had handle that aswell..But your code works well :)

Comment: Hey, how to control the charset? I'm using the same method and some pdfs contain unknown characters and some not.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to open pdf file, pdf reader must have to be installed in your device.Otherwise it will show blank screen.
Also [here](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/pdf-from-server-example/) is good example to **download pdf from server** and **view its contents**.

Answer (score 0):

see http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html for retreiving data from a url with a DefaultHttpClient